# Rails Tutorial - Have to save users with validations off

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I've followed the rails tutorial and have a working users system, but one thing annoys me: When saving a user, even just in the console, I have to turn off validations since it will not save without both password and password confirmation saved, and set to the same thing.

This is a pain, and seems potentially dangerous if I added other important validations to the user. So is there a good way of dealing with this? Really I want the validation to apply only when the update is coming from the user, not from my own code.

So the user model has this:

```
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
  has_secure_password # this does the hashing, comparisions, etc for us.
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
```

This works great when the user is created, and for when the user is editing his/her profile since it requires that the password is entered again. But, for other edits, it's annoying. eg:

```
user = User.find_by_name("bob")
user.reputation = 200
user.save(validate: false) # I really don't want to have to care about password validations here.
```

Comment: Maybe flesh out your scenario a little more.  Are you trying to create a user before they've made a password?  Or does the system check for a password every time new data is saved?  Or some other situation I haven't mentioned?

Comment: I've edited this to explain it better.

Answer (score 3):

You can call

```
@user.save(:validate => false)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's what my question was - It's a real pain and seems potentially dangerous to do this every time I want to save a user.

Comment: It's dangerous not to check validations by default, beacause you can accidently corrupt your data... And that way if you really know what you are doing you can bypass validations

Comment: I agree with @Adrian.  It is not hard to set both the password and confirmation to the same thing.

Comment: What if I'm not changing the password though? If I set the password and confirmation to get past the validation, it'll save that.

Comment: normally password and password_confirmations are set to validate on creating object - after that their the same and pass validations on updating. If you want to create user without password you can make you life easier and generate secure random password or tweak your validations not to check password to the point you want it; it can be done with :if and/or :unless validation modifiers

Comment: Ok, but if I set them to validate on creation, I'll lose the benefit of having the validations when I do want them, which is when the user is editing their profile (I've added some more detail to the question)

Answer (score 0):

You could try just validating on create. That will make it so the password (or other variables) is only necessary on registration but not when youre editing an existing user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have control over which attributes to skip validations for, you may want to try using the ValidationSkipper gem:

https://github.com/npearson72/validation_skipper

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create different models for it, a secure model for logging & password changes, and a profile model for anything else, giving out reputations, medals, and stuff.

Creating new functions in the first model allows you to totally forget about the second one, like

```
def reputation value
    self.profile.reputation = value
    self.profile.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but if you want to update a single attribute you can use the update_attribute method which skips validation checks. In this case you could call

```
user.update_attribute :reputation, 200
```